# What is the error in following mysql query for making trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

Please can someone explain what is the syntax error in the following mysql command to create the trigger

```
create trigger comment_on_network 
after insert on network_comments
for each row begin 
declare @ansh INT(2); 
set @ansh=(select count(*) from network_comments where
network_comments.network_id=NEW.network_id);
update networks set networks.no_of_comments=@ansh where
networks.network_id=NEW.network_id;
END;
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about any error but the below line to set @ansh

```
set @ansh=(select count(*) from network_comments where
network_comments.network_id=NEW.network_id);
```

should be

```
set @ansh := (select count(*) from network_comments where
network_comments.network_id=NEW.network_id);
```

Also, don't think this declare statement needed `declare @ansh INT(2);`